# configuration TextView inside java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Previously, I had the file res\layout\main.xml:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.98"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showmsg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/textshowmsgcolor"
    android:textSize="10dp" />
</ScrollView>
```

I need to dynamically create a TextView, so now I have res\layout\main.xml:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.98"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#112222"));
    tv.setId(windows.size()+100);
    tv.setTextSize(10);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout2).addView(tv);
```

Windows are created dynamically. Unfortunately, when the window is
completely filled with text, scrolling does not move. Tell me please
how to write my old settings into java code?

Comment: in which direction do you want it to move? horizontally, or vertically?

Comment: why you want multiple `TextViews` horizontally? Why not just add all text in one string and set to a single `TextView` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to make your LinearLayout horizontal? You probably want to use a vertical LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: this will help if he wants to add more TextViews vertically. but his layout should still scroll if the single TextView overflows vertically

Answer (score 0):

```
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
((LinearLayout) linearLayout2).addView(tv);
```

Its looks like your adding the textviews to the linearlayout, which doesnt not scroll when its full. You need to add the textviews to the scrollview in order for the scrolling to work.

Here is how I would do it

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.98"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical" ></ScrollView>
```

Then in a Java class.

```
// First declare the scrollview
scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.YOURSCROLLVIEWSID);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
// Set textsize, color, etc here.
scrollview.addView(tv);
```

Test it out. :)

Comment: using the linearlayout should work fine. the linearlayout gets the size of the textview inside it, and will scroll

Comment: Oh, okay! Ignore my answer then. :-)